# Is the set described a ball in a metric space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a subspace of the metric space $X$.   Let $x$ be a point of $X$.     Consider the intersection, $B(x,\epsilon/2)\,\cap\,Y$. $\,$ Let $y$ be a point of that intersection. $\,$ Consider the intersection, $B(y,\epsilon)\,\cap\,Y$.  Though $B(x,\epsilon/2)\subset B(y,\epsilon)$, there may be points of the open ball, $B(y,\epsilon)$, that do not belong to the subspace, $Y$.  If the balls centered at $x$ cover $X$, then the balls centered at $y$ cover $Y$.  But the latter do not all necessarily belong to $Y$. They do cover $Y$ as balls in $X$, true. Their intersections with $Y$ do cover $Y$ in the subspace $Y$, but I do not think they are correctly termed open balls in $Y$.  $\,\,$ There is a statement "Any subspace of a totally bounded metric space is totally bounded."$\,\,$A proof of the statement calls the $y$-centered intersections a cover for $Y$ that demonstrates $Y$ is totally bounded.  Is that correct? $\,$  If it is not correct, is there a proof of the statement that is correct?

Comment: If $y\in Y$ and $\epsilon>0$, the open $\epsilon$-ball in $Y$ centred at $y$ is $B_Y(y,\epsilon)=B_X(y,\epsilon)\cap Y$.

Comment: The problem with that is that every subset *is* a subspace. $B_X(y,\epsilon)\cap Y)$ is an open ball in $Y$ when $Y$ is viewed as a space in its own right; it is not (in general) an open ball in $X$ that happens to be a subset of $Y$.

Comment: If Y were merely a subset of X, rather than a subspace, then $B_X(y,ϵ)∩Y$ would not be called a ball as in the present case. Am I correct in understanding this?  – goedelite 5 mins ago

Comment: It's still a $Y$-open ball in $Y$; depending on what one is doing this may or may not be of interest. In one and the same argument you may have to consider it both ways.

Comment: Understood!  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!